Create the ls.exe --color=auto alias on Powershell
So on Linux almost everyone has in their shell startup scripts:
alias ls="ls --color=auto"

I have ls that is seems to be aliased to the dir command on my PowerShell. I installed ls.exe via scoop install coreutils, and I want to "alias" ls to ls.exe with the --color=auto argument. I read here that one has to use a function to wrap ls.exe, but I don't know how to do that.

The about_Aliases item may help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-7.4#alternate-names-for-commands-with-parameters

make a function; powershell 7 get-childitem has colors btw

It's a little tricky to delete an alias in powershell 5.1.  Otherwise a function won't override an alias.  I don't have ls, but I tested with echoargs.
remove-item alias:ls   # delete from alias drive
function ls { ls.exe --color=auto $args }  # $args has optional arguments

